# How can I run a precombiled or published ASP.net MVC project and add files to it and publish it again?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a published ASP.net MVC project with bin folder that has dll files.

I want to add model, controllers, and views as new pages with a source code and re-puplish it again.

I have tried to create a new project and add the published files and add references to the all dll files, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem statement.  Are you getting error messages?  Do you have the source code for the original DLL files?

Comment: So you don't have source code? Then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504504/get-source-code-of-my-published-asp-net-website-from-server

Comment: Basically you have the dlls and want to create a project based on them?

Comment: I don't have the source code, I have the dll files and I need to create a project based on them and add some pages to it

Comment: Reverse engineering is your option in this case.

Comment: Ok I will try decompilers, thank you all